# Problem with bigger than sign on my landing page

Tags: html

i try to wrap my page head in a header an while i use  on my page appears a ">". I can overlapp it with a picture or something but why i appears anyway ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
  <head>
    <title>Wilkommen</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
  </head>
    <body>
        <!--Kopfzeile mit Navigation-->>
        <header id="header">
                <img src="images/logo_placeholder.png" alt="logo" class="logo">
        </header>  
    </body>
</html>
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an extra `>` in your comment `<!--Kopfzeile mit Navigation-->`**>**